# How to return a Razor Component from code-behind?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a `MyPage.razor` Razor Component. How can I return the rendered version of it when I use JavaScript's `fetch()`?

```
public async Task<...> OnGetFetchMyPage(/* config here */) {
    return ... // what is the interface and class that I should use?
}
```

Should I include the component into a Partial View and then return the partial view instead?

Comment: I don't understand why you wanna use `fetch()` to render razor component? If you wanna render razor component dynamically, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0)